# Cannot hook with DownloadManager.class

Tags: android, xposed

I tried to hook a method `request(Uri);` in **DownloadManager** class of android.app package but it is not calling the method logic implemented by me. The code is as below. Other modules are working well.

```
Class<>download=XposedHelpers.findClass("android.app.DownloadManager",loadPackageParam.classLoader);

XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(download, "request", Uri.class,new XC_MethodHook() {@overrideprotected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {Log.e("WTKLV","CALLED);}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the other overload to hook a method [findAndHookMethod](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedHelpers.html#findAndHookMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

```
XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("android.app.DownloadManager",loadPackageParam.classLoader, "request", Uri.class,new XC_MethodHook() 
{
    @Override
    protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable 
    {
         Log.e("WTKLV","CALLED);
    }
});
```

Also check that it can throw `NoSuchMethodError` in case the method was not found and `XposedHelpers.ClassNotFoundError` in case the target class or one of the parameter types couldn't be resolved. So if it doesn't work verify that so you can get to the exact problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No i could not resolve the issue. There is no error throwing in my method. But it is simply not working.